# Cannot view Jenkins available plugins

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I successfully launched Jenkins with the following command

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

Then I went to the Manage Plugins page and clicked on the Available tab. It looked like my browser (firefox) was trying to download something but nothing happened. I don't use Maven. In the Advanced tab the update website is set to https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json, user name is set to admin and password is set to a hidden value. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It eventually displayed the plugins but it took a long time probably because they are many and are all downloaded at the same time.